# How to connect to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database

I am conecting mongo db everyday ,it worked fine but today it troubled me with the below error,can anyone help me please.

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.10
```

connecting to: test
2017-01-10T14:26:13.073+0530 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2017-01-10T14:26:13.074+0530 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146
exception: connect failed

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
sudo service mongod restart
```